# get formatted date from timestamp using DateTime

Tags: php

my code is :

```
$d_actual_timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$actual_timestamp);
```

`$d_actual_timestamp` actually contains :

```
DateTime Object
(
 [date] => 2015-08-07 07:55:23
 [timezone_type] => 1
 [timezone] => +00:00
)
```

How can i get only `07/08/2015` from `$d_actual_timestamp` ? I need it in that specific format to query my database.**EDIT** Tried `$d_actual_timestamp -> format('d/m/Y');` but i did not work.
thanks.

Comment: What "but i did not work"? How did it "not work"? `$d_user_timestamp -> format('d/m/Y');` should return a string containing `07/08/2015`.... what did it return instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp is stored in `$d_actual_timestamp` but you are trying to get a date from `$d_user_timestamp`.

Use `$d_actual_timestamp->format('d/m/Y');`

Comment: that was a mistake i made when i was writing the question..thanks for pointing it out ^^ +1 (will correct my question).